# In Jetty/Jersey I use a filter for custom auth headers to get mapped to user roles. How do I accomplish this using ReSTlet?

Tags: authentication, servlets, jax-rs, servlet-filters, restlet

In the current version of my application, I have a Servlet filter which looks for custom headers and maps those headers into role information which is then passed to my Jersey JAX-RS servlet. I would like to implement a compatible solution using ReSTlet, but Guards do not seem to be able to do what I want and RoleChecker is deprecated. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Jax-rs extension lacks the support of the @Context annotation.
An issue is opened: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/532